# MYSQL Select rows not more than necessary

Tags: mysql, select

Table:

```
ID | DATETIME (YmdHis) | MONEY | USERID
========================================
1  | 20180219120011    | 200   | 1
2  | 20180220041910    | 20    | 2
3  | 20180221185913    | 53    | 1
4  | 20180222165934    | 220   | 2
5  | 20180222015925    | 10    | 1
6  | 20180223021205    | 30    | 1
7  | 20180224034909    | 20    | 2
8  | 20180224034909    | 35    | 2
9  | 20180226021205    | 55    | 1
10 | 20180226021205    | 115   | 2
```

I need to select ONLY rows when specific user's MONEY SUM achieves specific amount and not more. And sort those rows by DATETIME ASC. 
USERID  and SUM is input data.
For example, 
1) for SUM = 250 and USERID=1 i need to get those rows ID: 1 and 3 (SUM = 253). 
2) for SUM = 250 and USERID=2 i need to get those rows ID: 2, 4 and 7 (SUM = 260).

Comment: What is your code so far? Looks like you should use a join table to filter results

Answer (score 1):

In this solution the innermost query (s) figures out the cumulative money total by userid in id order, the next innermost query (s1) figures out the earliest id where the cumulative sum >= 250 and the outermost query joins all the ids <= to the minid found by s1.

```
select t.*
from t
join
(
select userid,min(id) minid
from
(
select id,money,userid,
         (select sum(t1.money) from t t1 where t1.USERID = t.userid and t1.id <= t.id) cumsum
from t 
order by userid ,id
) s 
where cumsum >= 250
group by userid
) s1 on s1.userid = t.userid and t.id <= s1.minid
order by t.userid, t.id
```

result

```
+------+-------+--------+
| ID   | MONEY | USERID |
+------+-------+--------+
|    1 |   200 |      1 |
|    3 |    53 |      1 |
|    2 |    20 |      2 |
|    4 |   220 |      2 |
|    7 |    20 |      2 |
+------+-------+--------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

[DEMO using Rextester](http://rextester.com/BYJC31653)  My habit is to name tables the SO Question # with other attributes if more tables exist.   This helps ensure I don't overlap someone elses tables. However since this is only one table and the name of the table wasn't defined; I simply used the SO#

This is but one approach.  The same could likely be accomplished using a/an Window/Analytical functions in current versions of MySQL.  Not sure of your version.
.

In the below we simulate sum() over (partition by userID) to get a running total by user and then we set a user varible to denote which record we want to keep (including the first above 250; but no others)

1. Create a derived table using user variables to track a running total.
2. Use user variables to denote which records to include and keep a running total
3. Select from derived table where we denote to include records.
4. Note: The order of the user variables in the select matters.

.

```
SELECT ID, DateTime, Money, UserID, SumTotal
FROM (SELECT Id
           , DateTime
           , Money
# Next code line sets flag we use later to exclude unneeded records 
# to adjust the 250 simply change the 250 here to whatever 
# (or pass in as a parameter to a procedure.             
           , case when @RunTotal<=250 OR @CurUser<>UserID then @Inc:=1 else @Inc:=0 end as IncludeRecord 

# Next code line simulates sum analytical function to keep a running total 
# by user ordered by DatTime to keep track when we reach 250.
           , case when @CurUser<>UserID then @RunTotal:=Money else @RunTotal:=@RunTotal+Money end as SumTotal 

           , @CurUser:=UserID as userID
      FROM SO48989971
      CROSS JOIN (SELECT @RunTotal:=0.00,@Inc:=0,@CurUser:=0) InitUserVar #needed to initialize user variables.
      ORDER BY  UserID, DateTime Asc) DerTable
WHERE IncludeRecord = 1
ORDER BY UserID, DateTime;
```

Giving Us:

```
+----+----+----------------+--------+--------+----------+
|    | ID |    DateTime    | Money  | UserID | SumTotal |
+----+----+----------------+--------+--------+----------+
|  1 |  1 | 20180219120011 | 200,00 |      1 |      200 |
|  2 |  3 | 20180221185913 |  53,00 |      1 |      253 |
|  3 |  2 | 20180220041910 |  20,00 |      2 |       20 |
|  4 |  4 | 20180222165934 | 220,00 |      2 |      240 |
|  5 |  7 | 20180224034909 |  20,00 |      2 |      260 |
+----+----+----------------+--------+--------+----------+
```

thx P.Salmon missed an element.

Comment: Looks the right approach but misses id 2 for userid 2.

Comment: Yep logic issue: needed an `Or` on the sum total check... to check if we had a new user.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT table_name.* 
FROM table_name INNER JOIN 
     (SELECT USERID, SUM(MONEY) 
      FROM table_name 
      GROUP BY USERID 
      HAVING SUM(MONEY) >= 250) AS helper 
ON table_name.USERID = helper.USERID 
ORDER BY DATETIME;
```

Comment: Please use `inner join on` syntax. Avoid the old join style.

Comment: it's not what the OP asked actually, he wants the bare minimum result, yet one that is big enough among the rows for a certain user

Comment: Promote the use of  explict `JOIN` sintaxis, Aaron Bertrand wrote a nice article [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) about it.